# How do I make it so that when the player joins the world in MC 1.18.2 Forge, a message is sent out that is clickable in chat?

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am trying to make a message be sent out in chat when a player joins a world using my mod in 1.18.2 forge (Minecraft) that, when clicked, trys to open a link to the bugs page on github. I can't find out, however, how to make it open a link, as it is not working with my current code, and all tutorials are outdated. Thank you in advance.

Also, if it is easier, running a tellraw command that is clickable would be great, but all tutorials on running commands are also outdated. I already know how to make the command, but I don't know how to make the game execute the command.

My code:

```
@SubscribeEvent
    public static void onEntityJoinWorld(@NotNull EntityJoinWorldEvent event) {
        if(event.getEntity() != null && event.getEntity() instanceof Player) {
            if(messageAlreadyReceived == 0) {
                messageAlreadyReceived = 1;
                Entity player = event.getEntity();
                String testVariable = "CLICK ME";
                String.format(testVariable, ClickEvent.Action.OPEN_URL, "https://www.google.com");
                player.sendMessage(new TextComponent(testVariable), player.getUUID());
            } else {
                messageAlreadyReceived = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Java 17.0.2
MC Forge 1.18.2-40.0.5

Comment: You format a String, [old forums say to register a click event as style](https://forums.minecraftforge.net/topic/85426-1152-how-to-add-a-shortened-hyperlink-to-the-chat/) (probably changed now). Found this for tellraw: https://www.minecraftjson.com/

Comment: @ivvija This sadly is outdated, and, as I should problably clarify, I just need to know how to execute the command.